# How to mock/trigger a $routeChangeSuccess in Angular unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Given a handler attached to the $routeChangeSuccess event to update the title property on $rootScope:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
  $rootScope.title = 'My title';
});
```

in unit tests, I expect that performing a route change would update the title property:

```
it('should set a title on $routeChangeSuccess', function () {
  $location.path('/contacts');
  $rootScope.$apply();

  expect($rootScope.title).toBe('My title');
});
```

However, the code in the $routeChangeSuccess handler never executes in tests. It executes fine and updates the title when running the application in the browser.

How can I trigger a $routeChangeSuccess event in tests? Is there a better approach to testing any arbitrary code that is attached to $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', ...) or other $routeChange events?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try sending out the event yourself.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('$routeChangeSuccess', eventData);
```

Comment: what do you pass through in eventData?

Comment: @DamonSmith `eventData` is optional but if the code under test uses it you'll need to create/mock it as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

A more behaviour driven approach is to do an actual navigation using

`$location.url()` or `$location.path()`

In order for this to work you need to do two things in your test:

1. you need to inject $route (even if you're not using it). This is, because $route adds an internal listener for $locationChangeStart, but it will only do so when $route is requested somewhere (and thus initialized)
2. you need to provide a dummy routing that you can navigate to:

   ```
   beforeEach(module(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/somePath', { template: '&nbsp;' });
   }));
   ```