# Testing controller with routeChangeSuccess but missing parameters

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to mock a route change success in order to write a test. A url i.e. 'example/:id' has been registered using routeProvider.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(angularEvent, current, previous) {
        var super_important_id = current.pathParams.id
        // Do something with super_important_id
})
```

I've tried

```
$location.path('/example/0')
$rootScope.$apply();
$rootScope.$broadcast('$routeChangeSuccess')
```

But it always throws this error when I run the test

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'current.pathParams')
```

How can I successfully mock the route change success event and make it fill in pathParams?

Answer (score 2):

If you're manually broadcasting the `$routeChangeSuccess` event, then you need to provide the arguments for it. Something like this:

```
var objToMockCurrentRoute = {
  pathParams: {
    id: "MY_ID"
    //any other needed properties
  }
  //any other needed properties
}
$rootScope.$broadcast('$routeChangeSuccess', objToMockCurrentRoute);
```

Without doing that, `current` is just `undefined`, which explains the error you're seeing.

Also, doing it this way means you don't need to call `$location.path`.

Comment: How come location can't trigger the routechangesuccsss event?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but it seems most people test the event manually as opposed to having angular trigger the event. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447988/how-to-mock-trigger-a-routechangesuccess-in-angular-unit-tests